# Can "As old As" mean just old enough?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Let's say X and Y are some artifacts that have been recently found. We know both belong to the prehistoric period. We also know some estimations on Y's age, as it'd been discovered earlier and has gone through different examinations. Now, we have some findings suggesting that X existed when Y was being built.

Which sentence makes sense?

> X is as old as Y

Or

> X is not as old as Y

Comment: Or "X is at least as old as Y"

Comment: @KillingTime Yes, I would use that if I was going to write this. I took a test today and the reason for this question is to understand the meanings of options.

Comment: If "X existed when Y was being built" then clearly the second statement is false, so the other one must be the correct answer, even if it isn't quite adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd read "X is as old as Y" to mean that X is at least as old as Y, and may be older. If you want to say that they were built at the same time, you'd say "X is the same age as Y."

"X is not as old *as* Y" states that Y was built before X, which is the opposite of the situation you described.

"X is older than Y" states that X was built first.

All those statements are pretty definite, you might want to modify that to show that the dating of these objects is uncertain: "X appears to be older than Y" "Y may not be as old as X."